# Cannot add plain C# file when project SDK is Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a project that started out as a console application (it still is), but where I added ASP.NET Core so I could also use the Kestrel web server to host a simple UI. To get that to work, I changed the `.csproj` file to use the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` SDK:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
...
</Project>
```

This makes everything work fine (if using `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` it cannot find the `AspNetCore` namespace), but when I want to add a plain and simple C# file, that template is not available when I do RMB -> Add New Item on the project.

I can easily add C# files by copying or creating an empty file and adding existing item, but because that option is not available from Visual Studio, I am getting the feeling I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I have the same problem, I'd really like to know if this is a deliberate thing or not!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the ASP.NET workload is installed on your computer.

- Run the Visual Studio installer
- **Modify** the installation
- Select **ASP.NET and web development**